# Replace discovery document endpoints in OpenIdConnectOptions Configuration without breaking the authorization flow (OpenID Connect .Net Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, openid-connect

How can I replace discovery document endpoints found in the OpenIdConnectOptions Configuration object without breaking the authorization flow?

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
   .AddCookie()
   .AddOpenIdConnect(SetOpenIdConnectOptions)
   ;
}

private void SetOpenIdConnectOptions(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"];
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ResponseMode = "query";

    //Option 1 - Set authority aka isssuer if discovery doc at default path e.g.https://someserver/.well-known/openid-configuration 
    //options.Authority = Configuration["AuthorityAddress"];

    //Option 2 - Explicitly set discovery document
    //options.MetadataAddress = "https://someserver/.well-known/openid-configuration"; 

    //Option 3 - Use configuration object and set URLs manually 
    var issuer = configuration["authorityaddress"];
    var authorization_endpoint = issuer + "/someidentityserver/authorize";
    var token_endpoint = issuer + "/someidentityserver/token";
    var userinfo_endpoint = issuer + "/someidentityserver/userinfo";
    var jwks_uri = issuer + "/someidentityserver/jwks";

    options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration()
    {
        AuthorizationEndpoint = authorization_endpoint,
        JwksUri = jwks_uri,
        TokenEndpoint = token_endpoint,
        UserInfoEndpoint = userinfo_endpoint,
        Issuer = issuer,
    };
}
```

Option 1 and 2 above work perfectly: I click a private page and can successfully log into my identity server, but if I comment them out and try to manually configure the endpoints, as seen in option 3, I get the following error:

> SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature
> validation failed. Unable to match key: kid: 'XXXXX'.

The kid is there and can be seen in the jwks_uri json.

I am redirected to my identity server, but after logging in, I am redirected to my application and then the error appears.

What further configuration am I missing? Do I need to add more to the new OpenIdConnectConfiguration object?

The .Net framework can clearly handle this when there is just a discovery document defined, so how can I trigger the same functionality?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error:

```
SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: kid: 'XXXXX'.
```

Then that is often because the signing keys has changed in IdentityServer and this can happen when you redeploy IdentityServer. So what you need to do is to create a signing key and persist it in some medium outside IdentityServer.

See this [link](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/keys/) for details.